# liquibase maven documentation out of date

Tags: liquibase

The maven documentation on the website looks out of date:

http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/maven_generateChangeLog.html

Points to version 3.2.0 of the plugin while the latest version is 3.4.1.

Where can I log a defect for this issue ? (which caused quite a bit of problems for me)

Comment: May be here? 
https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first comment is correct. https://liquibase.jira.com/projects/CORE/issues